# Using Modeshape 4.1.0 with Jboss EAP 6.3.0.GA

Tags: jboss-eap-6, modeshape

We want to use ModeShape 4.1.0.Final as a subsystem on Jboss EAP 6.3.0.GA . What are the steps and configurations for this?

ModeShape subsystem is available for WildFly 8.x but we do not want to use Wildfly on our production systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Modeshape 4.x releases sub-system has a number of dependencies on Wildfly 8.x components and can not be run as a sub-system on JBoss EAP 6.3.0.

The alternative to running Modeshape 4.x as a sub-system is to embed the it into your applications ear/war. For more information on how to do this see

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE40/ModeShape+in+web+applications

Comment: Sorry not to accept this on time @lucasweb , I just saw it was not selected.